# Why can I pull my gas script to local by clasp?

Tags: google-app-engine, clasp

### Premise · What I want to realize

I'm trying to clone my gas script by clasp from local, but I'm not going well...

### testing environment

- MacOS Mojave

  - 10.14.6
- node.js

  - 12.12.0
- npm

  - 6.11.3
- clasp

  - 2.3.0
- bash

  - 3.2.57

### What I did

**1. make the directory and move into it**

> $ mkdir /path/to/gasSample
>
> $ cd /path/to/gasSample

**2. init npm**

> $ init npm

```
{

  "name": "gcaltotalling",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**3. install clasp via npm**

> $ npm install clasp
>
> $ clasp --version

```
2.3.0
```

**4. login to clasp**

> $ clasp login

```
Logging in globally...
 Authorize clasp by visiting this url:
https://accounts.google.com....

Authorization successful.
```

> $  ls -la

```
... .
... ..
... .clasp.json
... package.json
```

**5. clone the target gas script**

> $ clasp clone [scriptId]

```
Project file (.clasp.json) already exists.
```

### Problems occurring · Error messages

> $ clasp pull

```
Could not find script.
Did you provide the correct scriptId?
Are you logged in to the correct account with the script?
```

### that's all

I got the errors. What shoud I do?
Could you lend me a hand? Thank you for your reading.

Answer (score 1):

Your output in point 5 means, you specified a wrong script-ID before. When repeating the command, you get that output. Simply delete that file and run clasp clone  again. Pay attention to use the script-ID and not the project-key.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you are managing the project in VSC. Here the fatastic things that you can do with CLASP:

1. I have a GAS project with (let's say) ID "A" after clasp login you can clone the project from GAS to VSC with clasp clone ID ("A")
2. I have a GAS project with ID "A" after clasp clone in VSC you can pull (from inside VSC) the project from GAS to VSC with clasp pull
3. I have a GAS project with ID "A"  in VSC you can push (from inside VSC) the project from VSC to GAS with clasp push
4. I have a GAS project with ID "A"  in VSC you can push (from inside VSC) in another GAS project (let's say ) ID "B" the whole project: the steps are - modifiy clasp.json inside VSC (change ID from A to B) and into the VSC terminal run clasp push. Important! you have to create project with ID "B" before to run clasp command